# Prove that Legendre polynomial satisfies $\int_{-1}^1 x P_n(x) P_m '(x) dx=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, legendre-polynomials

I am aware that I have to use the equations

$(1-x^2)P_m''-2xP_m'+m(m+1)P_m=0$

and

$(1-x^2)P_n''-2xP_n'+n(n+1)P_n=0$

but I have been unable to do so.

I tried integrating by parts, like in this question: [Prove that the Legendre polynomial satisfies $\int_{-1}^1(1-x^2) P_m' P_n' dx=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3339348/prove-that-the-legendre-polynomial-satisfies-int-111-x2-p-m-p-n-dx-0)

This gives me:

$\int_{-1}^1 x P_n P_m' dx= x P_n P_m \bigr |_{-1}^1-\int_{-1}^1P_nP_m dx-\int_{-1}^1 xP_mP_n'dx$

Again,

$\int_{-1}^1 x P_n' P_m dx= x P_n P_m \bigr |_{-1}^1-\int_{-1}^1P_nP_m dx-\int_{-1}^1 xP_m'P_ndx$

which is the same equation again.

This leads nowhere. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Use that $(1-x^2)P_m''-m(m+1)P_m=2xP_m^\prime$

to get
$$\begin{aligned}2\int_{-1}^1 x P_n P_m' dx &= \int_{-1}^1 (1-x^2)P_nP_m^{\prime \prime}dx-m(m+1)\int_{-1}^1 P_mP_ndx\\
&=\int_{-1}^1 (1-x^2)P_nP_m^{\prime \prime}dx
\end{aligned}$$

and use the previous question that you asked.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit Thanks for spotting the typo. I corrected.

Comment: So now integrating by parts get us back to where we started ?

Comment: lol ... there is minus sign that is bugging me now ... sorry Dude !

Comment: How is $\int_{-1}^1 x P_m P_n dx=0$? I thought the orthogonality meant $\int_{-1}^1  P_m P_n dx=0$? The 'x' is throwing me off. Edit Never mind, I got it. I have to integrate it by parts to get the result.

Comment: I'm integrating $\int_{-1}^1 (1-x^2) P_n P_m'' dx$ by parts with $u=(1-x^2)P_n$ and $v=P_m''$ to get $I=(1-x^2)P_nP_m'+I$. This yields no result...

Comment: It yields to $I=\int(1-x^2)P_nP_m'-I$.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net $$\int_{-1}^1 2xP_nP_m' dx=\int_{-1}^1 (1-x^2) P_n P_m'' dx$$ $$= (1-x^2) P_n P_m' - \int_{-1}^1 [-2xP_n+(1-x^2)P_n']P_m' dx $$ $$= (1-x^2) P_n P_m' - \int_{-1}^1 (-2xP_nP_m') dx - \int_{-1}^1 (1-x^2) P_n'P_m' dx$$ $$=  (1-x^2) P_n P_m' +\int_{-1}^1 (2xP_nP_m') dx$$. This gives me no result.